# String Fomat $, thousand separators with no decimal place

Tags: java-8, functional-programming

How do I format 234567 to $234,567?

was able to format as $234,567.00 using

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)
```

however, this is not what is needed.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html ?

Comment: Thank you sir! directed to right place

Answer (score -1):

You could remove the dot with the function split()

```
String amount = "$234,567.00".split('.')[0];
```

Comment: Appreciate your help!